# Subset a data frame based on a time sequence

Tags: r, time, sequence, subset

I have a data frame called DF with columns Time and Date. I would like to subset DF based on values in those columns. For the dates, I have a list of dates in DATES, and am subsetting DF rows where DF$Date is present in DATES. For the time, I would like to subset from 00:04:00 to 00:06:00. I do not know how to do the latter.

Ideally I would like to subset both by specifying the range, as in 00:04:00 to 00:06:00, as well as by specifying the starting point and minutes to look ahead, as in 00:04:00 and 3 minutes (two different methods). I guess it all comes down to making a sequence of time, and placing such sequence in a separate vector, which I can then use for matching.

Please note this is simply a short reproducible example. I am looking for a general way to do this because in practice I want to subset large spans of time. Please also note that even though in this example there is only one matching date, in practice there would be many matching dates spanning multiple years. That is why I believe it is not possible to use `POSIXlt` for making the time sequence. Thank you very much.

```
  #DF looks like this:
  #               DateTime  XXX      Time      Date
  #1371 2016-04-25 00:08:00  14 00:08:00 2016-04-25
  #1372 2016-04-25 00:07:00  13 00:07:00 2016-04-25
  #1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
  #1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 00:05:00 2016-04-25
  #1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 00:04:00 2016-04-25
  #1376 2016-04-25 00:03:00   4 00:03:00 2016-04-25
  #1377 2016-04-25 00:02:00   6 00:02:00 2016-04-25
  #1387 2016-04-24 23:52:00  41 23:52:00 2016-04-24
  #1388 2016-04-24 23:51:00  93 23:51:00 2016-04-24
  #1389 2016-04-24 23:50:00  53 23:50:00 2016-04-24

  #Code for DF, DATES, and to subset DF based on DATES
  DF <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 59L, 58L, 57L, 56L, 55L, 54L, 53L, 52L, 51L, 50L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), mday = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L), mon = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = c(116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L), wday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), yday = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), Open = c(14, 13, 14, 3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 15, 15, 23, 24, 33, 14, 65, 54, 41, 93, 53), Time = c("00:08:00", "00:07:00", "00:06:00", "00:05:00", "00:04:00", "00:03:00", "00:02:00", "00:01:00", "00:00:00", "23:59:00", "23:58:00", "23:57:00", "23:56:00", "23:55:00", "23:54:00", "23:53:00", "23:52:00", "23:51:00", "23:50:00"), Date = structure(c(16916, 16916, 16916, 16916, 16916, 16916, 16916, 16916, 16916, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915, 16915), class = "Date")), .Names = c("DateTime", "XXX", "Time", "Date"), row.names = c("1371", "1372", "1373", "1374", "1375", "1376", "1377", "1378", "1379", "1380", "1381", "1382", "1383", "1384", "1385", "1386", "1387", "1388", "1389"), class = "data.frame")
  DATES <- structure(c(12431, 12432, 10445, 10480, 11487, 12494, 12501, 12508, 13115, 13522, 14529, 15536, 16916, 16935), class = "Date")
  SELEC <- DF[DF$Date %in% DATES,]

  #Result of subsetting by Date:
  #                 DateTime XXX     Time       Date
  # 1371 2016-04-25 00:08:00  14 00:08:00 2016-04-25
  # 1372 2016-04-25 00:07:00  13 00:07:00 2016-04-25
  # 1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
  # 1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 00:05:00 2016-04-25
  # 1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 00:04:00 2016-04-25
  # 1376 2016-04-25 00:03:00   4 00:03:00 2016-04-25
  # 1377 2016-04-25 00:02:00   6 00:02:00 2016-04-25
  # 1378 2016-04-25 00:01:00   4 00:01:00 2016-04-25
  # 1379 2016-04-25 00:00:00  15 00:00:00 2016-04-25

  #How the final product would look like if using a larger data base spanning many years:
  #           DateTime XXX     Time       Date
  #2016-04-25 00:06:00  13 00:06:00 2016-04-25
  #2016-04-25 00:05:00  14 00:05:00 2016-04-25
  #2016-04-25 00:04:00   3 00:04:00 2016-04-25
  #2014-03-11 00:06:00  94 00:06:00 2014-03-11
  #2014-03-11 00:05:00   6 00:05:00 2014-03-11
  #2014-03-11 00:04:00  14 00:04:00 2014-03-11
  #2011-08-06 00:06:00  13 00:06:00 2011-08-06
  #2011-08-06 00:05:00  19 00:05:00 2011-08-06
  #2011-08-06 00:04:00  41 00:04:00 2011-08-06
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possibility 1: lexicographic comparison**

If all time values are stored as zero-padded 24 hour strings with the same delimiters, such as `%H:%M:%S`, then a lexicographic comparison can be used to apply the filter.

```
DF[DF$Date%in%DATES & DF$Time>='00:04:00' & DF$Time<='00:06:00',];
##                 DateTime XXX     Time       Date
## 1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
## 1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 00:05:00 2016-04-25
## 1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 00:04:00 2016-04-25
```

Lexicographic solutions are, of course, not ideal, because they do not lend themselves to time-based math, such as adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing, etc.

Better solutions involve transforming the time values to a numerical type that encodes time durations as an offset from an explicit or unspecified base time. This is how popular date/time libraries encode types, such as [boost date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) for C++, [Joda-Time](https://sr89j.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/a-look-at-the-internals-of-joda-time/) for Java, and POSIXct, difftime, and lubridate for R.

---

**Possibility 2: manual numerics**

It's possible to parse the strings ourselves to construct numerics representing the time durations, and use numerical comparison to apply the filter.

```
hmsToDouble <- function(hms) as.double(substr(hms,1,2))*3600 + as.double(substr(hms,4,5))*60 + as.double(substr(hms,7,8));
DF[DF$Date%in%DATES & hmsToDouble(DF$Time)>=hmsToDouble('00:04:00') & hmsToDouble(DF$Time)<=hmsToDouble('00:06:00'),];
##                 DateTime XXX     Time       Date
## 1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
## 1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 00:05:00 2016-04-25
## 1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 00:04:00 2016-04-25
```

---

**Possibility 3: POSIXt**

We can generate vectors of POSIXt (that is, POSIXct or POSIXlt) values and use vectorized comparisons against these vectors.

```
DF[DF$Date%in%DATES & DF$DateTime>=as.POSIXct(paste0(DF$Date,' 00:04:00')) & DF$DateTime<=as.POSIXct(paste0(DF$Date,' 00:06:00')),];
##                 DateTime XXX     Time       Date
## 1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
## 1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 00:05:00 2016-04-25
## 1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 00:04:00 2016-04-25
```

---

**Possibility 4: difftime**

The only built-in time duration data type in R is the [difftime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html) type, which can be a little bit finicky to work with. But for this problem, it's fairly straightforward.

```
DF[DF$Date%in%DATES & as.difftime(DF$Time)>=as.difftime('00:04:00') & as.difftime(DF$Time)<=as.difftime('00:06:00'),];
##                 DateTime XXX     Time       Date
## 1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
## 1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 00:05:00 2016-04-25
## 1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 00:04:00 2016-04-25
```

---

**Possibility 5: lubridate**

The [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) package is widely considered to be the best package for date/time handling in R. It provides a duration type which represents regular time durations, and a period type which allows representing counts of various irregular time units. Historically, date/time libraries have sometimes failed because they lacked an appreciation for the distinction between irregular time periods and regular time durations.

In the following solution, the `hms()` calls return instances of the period type, hence we are actually comparing separate time units. Incidentally, with respect to the actual storage of the separate time units, lubridate's design is to store the seconds values as the actual payload of the double vector, and the remaining units (minutes, hours, days, months, and years) as attributes on the object.

```
library(lubridate);
DF[DF$Date%in%DATES & hms(DF$Time)>=hms('00:04:00') & hms(DF$Time)<=hms('00:06:00'),];
##                 DateTime XXX     Time       Date
## 1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
## 1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 00:05:00 2016-04-25
## 1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 00:04:00 2016-04-25
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DF$Time <- strptime(DF$Time,format = '%H:%M:%S')

timeCondition <- (DF$Time >= strptime('00:04:00',format = '%H:%M:%S')) & (DF$Time <= strptime('00:06:00',format = '%H:%M:%S'))

SELEC <- DF[timeCondition & DF$Date %in% DATES,]
```

Which gives:

```
                DateTime XXX                Time       Date
1373 2016-04-25 00:06:00  14 2016-05-14 00:06:00 2016-04-25
1374 2016-04-25 00:05:00   3 2016-05-14 00:05:00 2016-04-25
1375 2016-04-25 00:04:00   2 2016-05-14 00:04:00 2016-04-25
```