# Chunk continuous timeseries data into non-continuous time windows for multiple time periods and multiple groups

Tags: r, group-by, time-series, many-to-many, subset

I have two datasets: `df1` contains windows of time that represent peak activity by `id`. These are non-continous time series, and there are multiple windows (events) per `id`, i.e. each `id` has multiple peak activity periods.  Below is a reproducible example I've made up but is not the real data (NOTE: I updated the data according to the comments below).

```
df1<-data.frame(start_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 10),
                end_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 05:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 10),
                             values=runif(20,10,50),id=rep(seq(from=1,to=5,by=1),2))
```

`df2` is a set of continuous timeseries of activity by `id`. I want to subset the `date.date` for each entry/peak activity in `df1` (by `id`).

```
date1<-data.frame(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2012-09-04 02:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 20), id=1)
date2<-data.frame(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-03 07:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 20),id=2)
date3<-data.frame(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 01:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 20),id=3)
df2<-data.frame(date=rbind(date1,date2,date3),values=runif(60,50,90))
```

The Goal: subset the continuous time series in `df2` only between the `start_time` to `end_time` in `df1` (by id), and keep the `values` field from each df. There is a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221947/subset-a-data-frame-based-on-a-time-sequence), but in that case the time period was static and known.  I am struggling with how to do this given the multiple events per id.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but in your example none of the date-times in df2 overlap with any of the date-times in df1. Are you wanting to consider the time of day only, (i.e. ignoring the date), or is the example your gave needing revised, or have I just not grasped the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I made the same observation regarding the lack of overlap. Hence my assumption that Laura is looking at the time stamp only and not at the date. See my answer below.

Comment: actually the times and dates should overlap, and I need both - the problem is in my MRE.  I will update it.  Despite that, @Paul, your solution works for me with a little bit of tweaking -  essentially preserving the full date structure `strftime(Start.Time..UTC., format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` has the function `foverlaps`, which does what you need.

`foverlaps` stands for “fast overlap joins”.  The function takes two data frames  (data.tables in this case) and returns the join.

Both data.tables need a `start` and `end` columns to calculate the overlaps. Since you only have one date column in `df2`, I’m just creating a `dummy_end` column with the same date as `date.date` in `df2`.

You can use the options `by.x` and  `by.y` to indicate the `start` and `end` columns. However, you can also use keys to do so using the `setkey` statement. The last two elements of the `setkey` must be the `start` and `end` columns. The advantage of using `setkey` is that you can add additional keys (before start and end) to filter the join further. In the present case, I’ll also set a key for `id`.

The `[, dummy_end := NULL]` is used to delete the dummy_end column.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)
setnames(dt2,"date.id","id") #change name to "id" for easier comparison
dt2[, dummy_end := date.date] #create dumme end date column 
setkey(dt1, id, start_date, end_date)
setkey(dt2, id, date.date,  dummy_end)

foverlaps(dt2, dt1, nomatch = NULL)[, dummy_end := NULL]
```

In terms of performance, `foverlaps` is marginally faster than `dplyr` for this particular problem (but still slower than base R). Indeed, you can see below that I reran Paul's microbenchmark to add `data.table`. However, I like the clean and simple `data.table` syntax.

**DATA and Benchmark**

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(start_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 00:00:00"), 
       by = "hour", length.out = 10),
       end_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 05:00:00"), 
       by = "hour", length.out = 10),
       values=runif(20,10,50),id=rep(seq(from=1,to=5,by=1),2))

date1 <-data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2012-09-04 02:00:00"), 
                              by = "hour", 
                              length.out = 20), id = 1)
date2 <-data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-03 07:00:00"), 
                              by = "hour", 
                              length.out = 20),id = 2)
date3 <-data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 01:00:00"), 
                              by = "hour", length.out = 20),id = 3)
df2 <-data.frame(date = rbind(date1,date2,date3), values = runif(60,50,90))

dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)
setnames(dt2,"date.id","id") #change name to "id" for easier comparison
dt2[, dummy_end := date.date] #create dumme end date column 
setkey(dt1, id, start_date, end_date)
setkey(dt2, id, date.date,  dummy_end)

dplyr2 <- function(df1, df2) {
  df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id" = "date.id")) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(date.date >= start_date &
             date.date <= end_date) %>%
    select(start_date,
           end_date,
           x_values = values.x,
           y_values = values.y,
           id,
           date.date) %>%
    ungroup()
}

baseR2 <- function(df1, df2) {
  df_bR <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "id", by.y = "date.id")
  df_bR <- subset(
    df_bR,
    subset = df_bR$date.date >=  df_bR$start_date &
      df_bR$date.date <=  df_bR$end_date,
    select = c(start_date, end_date, values.x, values.y, id, date.date)
  )
}

data.table2 <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  foverlaps(dt2, dt1,nomatch = NULL)[, dummy_end := NULL]
}


microbenchmark(baseR = baseR2(df1, df2),
               dplyr = dplyr2(df1, df2),
               data.table=data.table2(dt1, dt2),
               times = 50)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr    min     lq     mean median     uq     max neval
      baseR 1.2328 1.3973 1.632302 1.4713 1.5596  7.0549    50
      dplyr 8.2126 8.6865 9.628708 8.8531 9.2621 19.5883    50
 data.table 6.6931 7.3884 7.974340 7.9406 8.3973 11.0060    50
```

Comment: agree - i like the DT cleanliness.  thanks for the alternate, even if its slower.

Answer (score 3):

Your goal is not entirely clear to me but this is my reading: if the time (ignore date) in date.date is within start_date and end_date you would like to subset by Id.

Here's how I approached this:

```
library(dplyr)

df1<-data.frame(start_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 10),
                end_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 05:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 10),
                values=runif(20,10,50),id=rep(seq(from=1,to=5,by=1),2))

date1<-data.frame(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2012-10-01 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 20), id=1)
date2<-data.frame(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-10-01 07:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 20), id=2)
date3<-data.frame(date=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-10-01 01:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 20), id=3)
df2<-data.frame(date=rbind(date1,date2,date3),values=runif(60,50,90))

df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id" = "date.id")) %>%
  mutate(date.date.hms = strftime(date.date, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
         start_date.hms = strftime(start_date, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
         end_date.hms = strftime(end_date, format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>%
  mutate(date.date.hms = as.POSIXct(date.date.hms, format="%H:%M:%S"),
         start_date.hms = as.POSIXct(start_date.hms, format="%H:%M:%S"),
         end_date.hms = as.POSIXct(end_date.hms, format="%H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(date.date.hms >= start_date.hms & date.date.hms <= end_date.hms) %>%
  select(start_date, end_date, x_values = values.x, y_values = values.y, id, date.date) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This results in the following data frame:

```
> df
# A tibble: 62 x 6
   start_date          end_date            x_values y_values    id date.date          
   <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
 1 2014-09-04 00:00:00 2014-09-04 05:00:00     31.5     77.5     1 2012-10-01 00:00:00
 2 2014-09-04 00:00:00 2014-09-04 05:00:00     31.5     54.5     1 2012-10-01 01:00:00
 3 2014-09-04 00:00:00 2014-09-04 05:00:00     31.5     70.3     1 2012-10-01 02:00:00
 4 2014-09-04 00:00:00 2014-09-04 05:00:00     31.5     85.5     1 2012-10-01 03:00:00
 5 2014-09-04 00:00:00 2014-09-04 05:00:00     31.5     82.2     1 2012-10-01 04:00:00
 6 2014-09-04 00:00:00 2014-09-04 05:00:00     31.5     57.4     1 2012-10-01 05:00:00
 7 2014-09-04 01:00:00 2014-09-04 06:00:00     37.0     78.8     2 2014-10-02 01:00:00
 8 2014-09-04 01:00:00 2014-09-04 06:00:00     37.0     51.9     2 2014-10-02 02:00:00
 9 2014-09-04 02:00:00 2014-09-04 07:00:00     34.1     85.8     3 2015-10-01 02:00:00
10 2014-09-04 02:00:00 2014-09-04 07:00:00     34.1     69.4     3 2015-10-01 03:00:00
```

My approach was to first join the DFs by Id and then split the time information from the date (in the .hms columns) as a string and convert this back to a POSIXct object. This adds today's date to the time but that's ok if I just want to apply a filter on the time (and not the date). This results in a DF where the records have a date.date TIME within start_date and end_date. 
it is now easy to subset by Id column.

Is this what you are after?

UPDATE

LauraR explained that there is overlap in the dates in df1 & df2. She updated df1 & df2 in her example. With that update I can rewrite the code without the conversions of POSIXct to character and vice versa. it appears that as.POSIXct is a slow operation.

I can now do the following:

- remove all the date-time conversions and only check if the date-time in df2 is within the date-time range of df1
- rewrite the code in dplyr and baseR: we know that the pipe creates substantial overhead.
- turn the code into functions so I can benchmark them.

With the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

df1 <- data.frame(start_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 00:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 10),
                  end_date=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 05:00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 10),
                  values=runif(20,10,50),id=rep(seq(from=1,to=5,by=1),2))

date1 <-data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2012-09-04 02:00:00"), 
                              by = "hour", 
                              length.out = 20), id = 1)
date2 <-data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-03 07:00:00"), 
                              by = "hour", 
                              length.out = 20),id = 2)
date3 <-data.frame(date = seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-04 01:00:00"), 
                              by = "hour", l
                              ength.out = 20),id = 3)
df2 <-data.frame(date = rbind(date1,date2,date3), values = runif(60,50,90))

dplyr2 <- function(df1, df2) {
  df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id" = "date.id")) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(date.date >= start_date &
             date.date <= end_date) %>%
    select(start_date,
           end_date,
           x_values = values.x,
           y_values = values.y,
           id,
           date.date) %>%
    ungroup()
}

baseR2 <- function(df1, df2) {
  df_bR <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "id", by.y = "date.id")
  df_bR <- subset(
    df_bR,
    subset = df_bR$date.date >=  df_bR$start_date &
      df_bR$date.date <=  df_bR$end_date,
    select = c(start_date, end_date, values.x, values.y, id, date.date)
  )
}

data_baseR <- baseR2(df1, df2)
data_dplyr <- dplyr2(df1, df2)

microbenchmark(baseR = baseR2(df1, df2),
               dplyr = dplyr2(df1, df2),
               times = 5)
```

This code is a lot faster than before and I am sure it will require less memory. Comparing between dplyr and baseR:

```
> data_baseR <- baseR2(df1, df2)
> microbenchmark(baseR = baseR2(df1, df2),
+                dplyr = dplyr2(df1, df2),
+                times = 5)
Unit: microseconds
  expr    min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
 baseR  897.5  905.3 1868.66  991.2 1041.0 5508.3     5
 dplyr 5755.9 5970.2 6158.88 6277.4 6393.3 6397.6     5
```

shows that the baseR code runs a lot faster.

Comment: this solution works great, with a little tweaking of the dates to get the full date (my issue).  The only thing is that when I apply it to my full dataset, its extremely slow and bails out due to memory, so I may have to chunk the chunks...

Comment: Hi Laura, based on your comment and update I expanded my response.